# Create a List<Pair<L,R>> in Java with support .get(key) method like a map.

Tags: java, list, collections, dictionary

I want to store distinct values of Strings with an integer associated with them. I have a Pair class that I have to use and a Collection that I have to return.
Is there any possible way to access the integer using a Collection.get(String key) method like a Map class can do?

Comment: Why not just use a `Map` in the first place?

Comment: I have to return Collection not a Map.

Comment: Why?  Can you change the code that expects a Collection instead?  Or can you pass back the `entrySet()` of the `Map` for external code that needs a collection?

Comment: I can't (it's an exercise). I want to have a Collection that is sorted and also I want this Collection to act like a Map, I mean to have a key and value. But instead of Map<Key,Value> I want a declaration like Collection<Pair<Key,Value>>. How can achieve the same complexity with a Map?

Comment: To achieve the same algorithmic complexity?  You'll have to have a `Map` inside the `Collection` anyway.  But is this an actual assignment, or are you just trying to shoehorn a `Map` into a `Collection` for the lulz?

Comment: I am just trying to achieve optimal algorithmic complexitity. The problem actually is.
You have a stream of chars. You have to isolate words (check for space characters etc) and return the word occurrence in the whole text. The return type should be Collection<Pair<String,Integer>>.
What I did was to create a Map and easily find the word occurence and then copy the map (creating new Pair objects ) to a TreeSet<Pair>(new myPairComparator); How can I improve this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: That works just fine.  (But whoever wanted you to use a Collection<Pair<String, Integer>> is still being just plain silly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a new class that extends `ArrayList<Pair<String,Integer>>`

For example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Test extends ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>>{

    public Integer get(String value){
        for (Pair<String, Integer> item : this){
            if (item.getKey().equals(value)){
                return item.getValue();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best choice here is to implement a class with a `List<Pair<String, Integer>>` attribute inside.

```
public class MyMap {
    private List<Pair<String, Integer>> myList;

    ...

    public Integer get (String value) {
          for (Pair<String, Integer> p : myList)
             if (p.getKey().equals(value))
                 return p.getValue();
          return null;
    }
}
```